Account Status/Login on Main Menu with Avatar Pictures
How are you doing today?
I'm currently working on my eCommerce and I can't seem to find any tutorial about this, so I decided to give it a shot around.
I got this Menu (see picture) working great already..

..but I was wondering if it's possible to add icons (like the Shopping Cart and the Search icons) on it, just like the picture below:

This icon is meant for people to login. Plus, when people log in (and they upload a custom picture for their profiles) I really want to push their profile picture to the Menu so it can look like this:

I'm unable to find anything online to do this exact thing. I can find things like "How to insert icons or pictures in the Main Menu", but that goes a little off for what I'm looking for.
I'm not looking for them to appear when clicked on the 'hamburger' icon, at the dropdown menu. The Shopping Cart and Search Icons appear only there, and I love it, but I can't seem to find anything online regarding this.
In summary, what I'm looking for is:

How to insert custom icons on the Main Menu, like 'My Account/Login'.
When people are logged in, the icon turns into the users' profile picture, if available.

Also, as you can see, the hamburger icon is kinda padding a little down, not straight aligned to the other icons. That's really not THAT important, it's just aesthetics, but I would love to know how to fix this and add these and maybe other icons.
This profile icon will definitely link to 'My Account' page, so people can easily login and know if they are already logged in. It's also very important to push their profile picture when available, to make it look neat and professional.
Can you guys give me some light on this?
I'm currently working with DIVI on WordPress, of course, plus WooCommerce.
I appreciate very, very much your time and effort!
Best regards,
MANZON

edit your question to show us the code you tried to do that.

Is this a custom theme, a child theme or a theme someone else built?  All of this makes a huge difference as to how you would approach doing this.  Using a custom theme, this would be relatively simple.

@mmm: I didn't use anything yet since this is a new ongoing project. I tried many time on other websites, but not this one, and now the time has come to make it happen. The other codes I used before involved putting images that appear on the dropdown menu instead of the Main Menu header site where Search and Shopping Cart is. I'm looking to add anything to the dropdown menu.

@TonyDjukic: It's a custom theme I made myself with ET's DIVI and it's not a child theme, the website is already up and running.

Divi is a theme... ...so are you building a child theme?  https://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/

@TonyDjukic Well, yes! Maybe! TBH, until this day, I’m not well aware of what a child theme means and how I can benefit from it  But yes, I mean.. I built my own design with DIVI. So I’m looking for onto how to do these things with it! Since it’s an eCommerce, I really need to know how to implement this customized icon on the menu bar like the Search and Shopping Cart ones. And how to push my users profile pics. You can actually take a look at “albumcoverwallpapers.com”. Maybe you can guide! I hope so, man! Thank you very much for your time though!

Depending on how far along you are, you should switch to a “child theme”.  A child theme is basically a way of editing the way a theme works, but without modifying the actual parent theme’s code, because modifying Divi’s code would result in your modifications being deleted whenever you update it.  (Which you should always do.) https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/divi-child-theme

I’ll definitely take a look at it, @TonyDjukic, thank you very much! You said it would be relatively simple to do what I’m looking for though! How would do it to make this possible? Let me know if you get any insight about how to put a custom icon in there and make it push my customers profile pictures when they are logged in! I’ll appreciate very much any help to make it happen! Thanks, man! Cheers!

Once you have your child theme, I can help you write a shortcode to drop into your header that will display what you're looking for.  Or better still, since you already have 2/3 of the icons you want, it might even be easiest to just write a JS that inject a third item.  I can help with that.
